# Best method to take the random number of the range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Best method use Math object for example to take the random number of:

- [a, b] (double - integer) (2 cases)
- (a, b) (double - integer)
- [a, b) (double - integer)
- (a, b] (double - integer)

Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
var rand = function(a,b){
    return a+Math.round((b-a)*Math.random());
}
var r = rand(5,10);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.extendedRandom = function(a,b,excludeA,excludeB, round)
{
    var start = a;
    var end = b;
    if(excludeA)
        start++;
    if(excludeB)
        end--;

    var res = (end-start) * Math.random();
    return start + (round ? Math.floor(res) : res);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest case is the third one, which is already the implementation of `Math.random` in JavaScript.

The first case is [answered by Trevor in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143723/write-a-truly-inclusive-random-method-for-javascript). Make sure to read the other answers and comments, though, to get a clear understanding of the implications.

Likewise, the fourth case is answered by nickf in that same question.

The second case could be handled by a variation of Trevor's answer:

```
function zero_exclusive_random(){
  var r = Math.random();
  return r == 0 ? zero_exclusive_random() : r;
}
```