# Generating random doubles in Java between 0 and 1 inclusively or [0..1]

Tags: java, random

Java `Math.random()` returns a random number in [0..1). Is there a way to make 1.0 inclusive? Eventually I would like to have a random number (floating point number) in a specific range such as [Min..Max]. We know that for integers it will be

```
Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
```

I reviewed answers shown below in "Random floating point double in Inclusive Range". Alex L. answer is very close, but it is not quite right as Kendall Prey commented.

```
function randomInRange(min, max) {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? ((1-Math.random()) * (max-min) + min) : (Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
}
```

To use it in a Monte Carlo simulation application, two boundaries should be either inclusive or exclusive exactly.

Comment: You don't actually want to do this, it doesn't do anything

Comment: With a random double the probability of hitting one exact number is actually infinitely small (since there are an infinite number of possible fractions between 0 and 1), which means that in practice even if you changed the random number generator to include 1.0, for all intents and purposes it would never return 1.0. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143723/write-a-truly-inclusive-random-method-for-javascript/2143750#2143750

Comment: I have found some helpful tips and insight about the same problem as nhouser9 suggested. Thanks for good comments by nhouser9. <><

Comment: But, this is in my coding assignment. I guess I will do it exclusive of 1. Youngsup Kim, did you find a way?