# Generate random number from 0 to 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random, numbers

How can I compute random number between 0 inclusive and 1 inclusive?
When I have Math.random() it is returning 0-0.9999999

I did not find any solution for that.

edit:
I think that it could be somehow this way:

```
const precision = 1000
let c = 0
let min = 2
let max = -2

while(c !== 20000){
   c++;
   let r = (Math.round(Math.random()*precision)/precision)/0.9999999999999;
   r = Math.round(r*precision)/precision
   max = Math.max(r, max)
   min = Math.min(r, min)
 }
console.log('max:', max, 'min:', min)
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried yet ?

Comment: Once go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143723/write-a-truly-inclusive-random-method-for-javascript

Comment: The probability of getting any particular number from a random float is basically zero. So even if you include `1` you won't ever get it.

Comment: 1 - Math.random() try this

Comment: @V but then you can't get zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133060/discussion-between-v-for-vendetta-and-fafl).

Comment: How many digits do you need in the random number?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you're looking for.

[Examples #4 on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: But this is for integers

Comment: if you exclude the Math.floor, it would be `Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;` ... ... or `Math.random() * 1`

Comment: @Jaromanda how does multiplying by 1 change anything?

Comment: it doesn't - I was merely pointing out how that code would "work" with a *float* range of 0...1 ... in other words, it would make no difference