# Why do people suggest Math.random() for generating a random double in Java within a range? Doesn't that exclude the upper limit?

Tags: java, math, random

I have seen this question asked and usually I see a formula:
Math.random() * (max-min) + min

But I don't understand how is this correct. It doesn't include the higher range limit, does it?

For example, (min, max) = (0, 3).

The problem is that `Math.random()` returns a random double in range [0.0, 1.0), so the higher limit is not included.
So even if I get the formula substituted with:
0.9999... * (3.0-0.0 = 3) + 0.0 = i wont get 3.0 exactly. at best it will be something like 2.9999..

Am I wrong?

Comment: "I have seen this question asked and usually I see a formula" do those questions/answers state the range, as in, does anybody claim anything other than it generates a number in the range [max..min)?

Comment: (Ofc, I mean [min..max), silly typo)

Comment: You are not wrong. But why is that a problem? It's consistent with all the methods of [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) that accept min and max values (min is always inclusive, max is always exclusive).

Comment: That formula is only for value in [min, max). You want [min, max], so you can't use that formula.

Comment: So is there a way to get [min, max] ?

Comment: You are right, but you shouldn't bother since there would be less than 0.0000000000001%  probability of getting exactly 1, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143723/write-a-truly-inclusive-random-method-for-javascript
(that's one in some billions of billions)

Comment: A better way to get a random number in the range `[min, max)` is to call `nextDouble(min, max)`. That is also with exclusive max, but in most cases that's what you want (or you just shouldn't care if max is exclusive).

Comment: Are you looking for an INTEGER between 0 and 3 (inclusive), or a DOUBLE between 0 and 3 (inclusive).

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can slightly modify the `Random.nextDouble()` method as follows to obtain a random number in [min, max], in other words both `min` and `max` are *possible* outputs:

```java
public static double nextDoubleInclusive(Random rand, double min, double max) {
    return rand.nextDouble(min, Math.nextUp(max));
}
```

`Math.nextUp(max)` returns the next `double` after max. For example, `Math.nextUp(3.0)` equals `3.000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`.

As others have noted, the probability of an individual `double` value is very, very small, so whether this fix buys you anything depends on the full context of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a whole load of issues here.

### The programmer's way: `[start, end)`.

In most programming languages, we start counting from 0, and any ranges are put in the form of the start number being *inclusive* and the end number being *exclusive*. In other words, if I tell you: Loop from 5 to 9, I mean: "Loop for values 5, 6, 7, and 8".

This somewhat weird way to do things has advantages. Mostly, that consistency is nice - we have to decide on *something*, and programmers mostly decided on 'start from 0, starts are inclusive, ends are exclusive'. If you want to know why, well, probably because that way, the size of the range is simply `end-start` (9-5 is 4. Which is exactly how many numbers are in `[5, 6, 7, 8]`).

Hence, when you read: "Generate a random number between 1 and 4", that actually means: "Either 1, or 2, or 3", which is what `(int) (Math.random() * (4-1) + 1)` **almost but not quite** does.

### We have APIs now

Generally if you read: "There is this common task and this weird math formula is how you accomplish this task", **that is completely wrong**. Not because the math is wrong, but, because, **programming languages have encoded that formula somewhere**. You should be using *that*, not repeating the mathy thing every time you need the task.

Specifically, 'I need a random number between A and B', regardless of whether you meant 'up to *and including* B' or 'up to but not including B' (which is the more common interpretation amongst programmers, see previous chapter), you'd use this instead:

```
Random r = new Random(); // get a source of randomness however you want
int randomDiceRoll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

`nextInt` does what you want: It generates an integer number from 0 or up, less than the argument, uniformly distributed. In other words, `nextInt(6)` generates with equal likelyhood one of the 6 values: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

(see how that 'ends are exclusive' thing works out? We pass the number 6, and the number of options that can come out are also 6. Starting to count from 0 is part of the 'blame' here).

This is more readable than the mathy thing. The same applies to any task that is even remotely complex. For example, if you search around for 'how do I shuffle a list', you'll end up at [the Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). **Do not implement this algorithm**. Just call `Collections.shuffle(list)`. Which **is** a Fisher-Yates. Baked into the JDK. Don't reinvent that wheel.

### ... primary reason: You'll do it badly.

Turns out `Math.random() * (max-min) + min` **is wrong**.

It's subtly wrong, but wrong.

Turns out `Math.random()`'s description that it 'generates a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive)' is wrong. Or at least, oversimplified.

And trivially so: Computers aren't magical. There are, literally, an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1. Computers cannot represent a choice amongst an infinite ocean of options.

So, Math.random()'s description is therefore trivially **incorrect**. It cannot possibly work that way unless your computer breaks the laws of the universe or has a magic wand. And it does not.

What's actually going on is: `double`, which is what Math.random() returns, cannot actually represent 'any decimal number'. It's limited by the laws of time, space, and math. It can represent at most 2 to the 64th power different numbers. That's a lot of numbers! But nowhere near the amount of numbers between 0 and 1, let alone between minus and plus infinity (what oversimplified explanations of double try to say it can cover).

Only about 2 to the 64th power numbers are 'representable' by `double`. Any other number is silently rounded to the nearest representable. Turns out 0.1 isn't representable. We can see this:

```
double v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(v == 1.0);
```

Run it. Seriously, take your time. Run it. It'll print `false` which is nuts. How in the blazes can the computer mess this up? ten times a tenth is, obviously, 1.0, no?

No. Because that 0.1 isn't actually 0.1 - 0.1 is not something a `double` can represent with total accuracy for the same reason you cannot write a third on a piece of paper with perfect accuracy in decimal representation (0.33333333.... you're going to run out of space eventually. A computer runs out of space too. one tenth works because we humans like decimal. Computers count in binary. a tenth is as impossible to do in binary as one third is in decimal).

Now, how many doubles even exist in the `[0.0-1,0)` range?

It's a lot. But it's a multiple of 2. Not surprising; computers love binary.

Now here's the problem:

If we take a number chosen randomly from `2*2*2*2*2*2*.....` different option, and we 'map' that into a choice amongst, say, 3 things, then.. think about it. That's not entirely 'fair'. Because 3 isn't nicely divisible by that `2*2*2*2*2*...` number we are sampling from. To keep the numbers manageable, let's say that there are only 8 possible values that `Math.random()` can return (`2*2*2`). How do you 'map' 8 numbers onto 3? We could go:

```
0 -> A
1 -> B
2 -> C
3 -> A
4 -> B
5 -> C
6 -> A
7 -> B
```

Note how C is slightly less likely than A and B here. If our initial number is not '0-7' but, say, 0-65535 (65536 is `2^16`), you have the same problem. It's a lot harder to notice (the B and C comes up 21845 times, the A 21846 times; A is *slightly* more likely).

**The `Math.random() * (max-min) + min` algorithm suffers from this ailment and is therefore *not* a fair algorithm.**

`rnd.nextInt(6)` **does not** suffer from this. It doesn't use that algorithm; it uses a different, slightly more complex one (it's not slower, don't worry), that is truly fair.

That's another excellent reason not to handroll those commonly applied algorithms: They are often subtly wrong, or inefficient, or otherwise not as good as whatever the core JDK libs have baked in.

### doubles are infinite... at least, that's what they model

There are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, therefore the nature of the bound (inclusive or exclusive, a.k.a. closed or open) is mathematically speaking irrelevant. If I ask you to give me a random number between 0 and 1 the odds that you end up at precisely, say, 0.125 is precisely 0%, because it's one of an infinite number of options and 1 divided by an infinity is 0.

Hence, there's no point *mathematically* to talk about whether you intended for that 'give me a number between 0 and 1' to imply an inclusive or an exclusive bound.

Of course, as per previous chapters, `double` is not quite that infinite. It's large, though. The odds that `.nextDouble(1.0)` generates precisely 0.0 is not literal zero but is *really* small. It is true that the odds it generates exactly 1.0 really is 0, because `nextDouble` will never do this, but, given that the odds are truly astronomical in the first place (something along the lines of 1/1000000000000000 - that's 15 digits), if it matters, that's.. kinda odd. You're not going to see it in your lifetime even if you generate 500 numbers every second for the rest of your life.

Comment: This is all very good advice, but the OP is asking for a random _double_, so why are you using `nextInt()`?

Comment: But what do we do, if the API does not provide what we need? Fisher-Yates is perfect example for this, if I want to shuffle a List, I can use `Collections.shuffle()`, but there is no API to shuffle an array of primitives, I have to implement the algorithm on my own, even if this is reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Chaosfire Sure, if you've checked and the core APIs just don't have what you need nor can you easily adapt your code so you can use what's there, you weigh the complications of writing and maintaining it yourself against adding a dependency that does it for you and act accordingly.

Comment: I dunno about this answer; I think it's preferable to get to the point. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed important to cover both ends of the interval from `min` to `max`, given a number generator which includes `min` and excludes `max`, you can construct a generator to cover both ends as follows:

1. Generate a number `x`.
2. If `x` is equal to `min`, then return `max`.
3. Otherwise, generate another number `y` and return it.

I think that overstates the probability of `max` by a factor `n/(n - 1)` where `n` is the number of possible values that could be returned by the original number generator. Given that `n` is something like `2^52`, I don't know if you could notice it.

This approach uses very nearly two numbers, on the average, to return one. There's probably ways to make that more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To get inclusive `max`, for integers you can just increase the `bound` parameter by 1 (the smallest possible positive nonzero value).

For doubles you can follow the same approach, but you have to choose an appropriately small value to increase the `bound` - otherwise the probability to get the max value will increase too much. [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) seems a good candidate for the purpose.

> A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double, 2<sup>-1074</sup>.

Using [RandomGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html) from java 17, an example implementation may look something like this:

```
public class InclusiveBoundRngDecorator implements RandomGenerator {

  private final RandomGenerator rng;
  private final double doubleOffset;

  public InclusiveBoundRngDecorator(RandomGenerator rng, double doubleOffset) {
    if (Double.compare(doubleOffset, 0.0) <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bound offset must be positive");
    }
    this.rng = rng;
    this.doubleOffset = doubleOffset;
  }

  public InclusiveBoundRngDecorator(RandomGenerator rng) {
    //default doubleOffset to the smallest possible positive nonzero value
    this(rng, Double.MIN_VALUE);
  }

  @Override
  public long nextLong() {
    return rng.nextLong();
  }

  @Override
  public double nextDouble() {
    return rng.nextDouble();
  }

  //delegate other methods to rng as well

  @Override
  public double nextDouble(double bound) {
    double result = rng.nextDouble(bound + doubleOffset);
    //for result greater than or equal to bound, return bound
    //otherwise return result
    return Math.min(result, bound);
  }

  @Override
  public double nextDouble(double origin, double bound) {
    double result = rng.nextDouble(origin,bound + doubleOffset);
    //same as above
    return Math.min(result, bound);
  }
}
```

Note that, considering the nature of real numbers, the probability of encountering a specific one (`max` in this case) is negligible.